# Managed property of SessionScoped bean in ViewScoped bean doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, portlet, managed-bean

I have two beans:

First bean is SessionScoped:

```
@ManagedBean(name="opBean")
@SessionScoped
public class OPBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3206256117530229543L;
private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OPBean.class);

private String testData;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    LOG.debug(this.getClass().getName() + " init");
}

// other logic and getters and setters
```

Second bean is ViewScoped:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
//@RequestScoped
public class POPBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger LOG = = LoggerFactory.getLogger(POPBean.class);

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{opBean}")
private OPBean opBean;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    LOG.debug(this.getClass().getName() + " init"); 
}
// other logic and getters and setters
```

Problem is that in second bean `POPBean` I can not change value of ManagedProperty `opBean.testData` so that it would be saved and preserved in session as it should be and accessible from view like `#{oPbean.testData}`. If I change second bean to SessionScoped or RequestScoped it works.

I am using PrimeFaces, JSF 2.0 and it is runnig on Apache Pluto like portlet app.

So major problem is that ViewScoped bean cannot have mangaed property of SessionScoped bean as it should.

Comment: Bean names aren't problem, I sad everything works great if second bean `OPBean` is RequestScope or SessionScope, but with ViewScope id doesn't work

Comment: Any idea why this won't work? Is it JSF 2.0 problem?